# Passing a reference of a UIView to the next UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have an application where I'm trying to pass a `UIScrollView` from one `UIViewController` to the next during a navigation transition. I'm trying to figure out in which methods I should make remove the `UIScrollView` from its `superview` and then attach it to the new `UIViewController`.

I did an `NSLog` in the `viewDiDisappear` / `viewWillDisappear` methods of the first `UIViewController` and the `viewDidAppear` / `viewWillAppear` methods of the second `UIViewController` and this is the order I got:

```
viewWillDisappear
viewWillAppear
viewDidDisappear
viewDidAppear
```

My question is, can I expect this to stay consistent for all transitions, or do these run on different threads and based on load times of certain things, can they vary?

EDIT: Bump

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question with questionable motivation. Is there a reason that the two view controllers can't each have their own scroll views? Moving views around like this seems like asking for trouble, e.g. you have to coordinate which controller has the scroll view at any given time. If the scroll view is just a reflection of the data stored elsewhere in the program, it's hard to see why each can't have its own.

Comment: @caleb - It's such a pain in the ass to replicate a UIScrollView that is zoomable and has an image, because you can scroll the content offset to be to a half pixel, but when you set it manually it rounds it to the nears pixel. I've figured out how to do it by just setting the imageview without scrolling or zooming it, but since im passing data between the view controllers, ie if the user pushes back button i have to send back some info anyway so it's just easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, when you try to add a view as a subview, and it already has a superview, it will be removed from its original superview before being added to the new superview (as per the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)... so don't really even have to worry about this as much as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

well, the right question to ask yourself is: when are your viewController visible/on display?

UIViewController A

UIViewController B

UIScrollView C

1:  A:viewWillDisappear -> A visible, B invisible (C must be in A)

2:  B:viewWillAppear -> A visible, B invisible (C must be in A)

2 to 3 transition: both A and B are visible

3:  A:viewDidDisappear -> A invisible, B visible (C must be in A)

4:  B:viewDidAppear -> A invisible, B visible (C must be in B)

as you can see you have a moment during transition when both view controllers view are visible, so you cannot just move C from a to b, you may think to a workaround...

maybe you can make a screenshot of A and add it to A over all objects, then move C to B and make the transition

or you could make a fade out of C in A, make the transition, then make a fade in of C in B...